How to add external non-volatile memory to a custom max 10 FPGA PCB?
I am doing an audio processing project (more of a learning opportunity than an actual product..). For this project I want to be able to make the FPGA (a max10, not sure how much LE I need tbh) play back some audio stored externally. I was thinking of doing this with an SD card.
If I were to use SDIO, are there any hardware/PCB considerations?
And then to interface with the SD card would it be best to just use the nios 2 soft core? I have no idea how I would be able to access specific files on the SD card with HDL and I imagine that it is pretty much impossible. Its been a while since I have used an FPGA.

This is a little too broad of a question; there are many ways to do this. Yes, you can access specific files with HDL (which I take to mean "without implementing an entire programmable processor"), but it might be easier to just use a serial flash chip with no filesystem to get in the way. And yes, you could interface with an SD card's filesystem using nios II or any other processor.
